# Como funciona essa regex em js?

Tags: javascript, regex

Encontrei na internet essa regex em javascript que formata valores monetários em R$:

```
Number( 1450999 )
.toFixed( 2 )
.replace( '.', ',' )
.replace( /(\d)(?=(\d{3})+,)/g, "$1," )
// 1450999 -> 1.450.999,00
```

Fiquei analisando por muito tempo e ainda não entendi como essa regex funciona. Por exemplo, no caso a regex faz uma busca global, mas se eu retiro esse parametro, o retorno é um match para o dígito 1:

```
Number( 1450999 )
.toFixed( 2 )
.replace( '.', ',' )
.replace( /(\d)(?=(\d{3})+,)/, "$1." )
// 1450999 -> 1.450999,00
```

A questão é a seguinte, como pode essa regex pegar o digito 1 como match se ele não é seguido por 3 dígitos e uma vírgula, assim como manda a regex. Não teria que pegar o dígito 0?

Comment: Porque o caracter "?" indica um match opcional que pode estar lá ou não

Comment: Tiraste o `g` nos dois exemplos... foi erro certo?

Comment: Na documentação de regex da mozilla, diz que esse é um "lookahead", e que nesse caso x(?=y), x só tem correspondencia se é seguido por y, então não seria opcional.

Comment: sim Sergio, removi sem querer :b

Comment: O link da documentação https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions. Por isso ainda não entendi como funciona essa regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando tens `.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+,)/g, "$1.")` o que se passa é o seguinte:

A linha `Number(1450999).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',')` transforma o teu numero numa string assim: `"1450999,00"`. E é sobre essa string que a regex atua:

- `(\d)` cria um grupo de captura só com numeros
- `(?=(\d{3}))` indica que o grupo de captura defenido antes deve procurar por  `(\d{3})`
- `(\d{3})+` cria um grupo de captura de numeros, agrupados 3 a 3, uma ou mais vezes (`+`)
- `,` indica que depois das capturas todas vêm uma virgula na string
- `g` indica que deve continuar a procurar depois de ter encontrado um primeiro *match*

depois o replace troca cada grupo de 3 numeros por esses 3 numeros **mas acrescentando** um ponto.

Há um site excelente para analizar expressões regulares. No teu caso seria assim: https://regex101.com/r/Z2UUIc/1

Comment: Ahhhh, agora entendi. O problema é que eu estava olhando para o '+' como regex, estava vendo como se fosse um adicional dizendo que seriam 3 dígitos + uma vírgula, mas no caso ele busca pelo precedente 1 ou mais vezes (no caso, \d{3}), assim como voce explicou. Valeu Sergio, consegui entender agora, obrigado!